# Session value is not saved sometimes in csv file

Tags: php, csv

I need to save a session value in .csv file, when I was trying on localhost, it was working fine, but now since I uploaded my project on some server, some users complained that there an issue with inserting/saving, when I checked the csv file, every info the users had entered is saved except the session value. I should indicate that this problem happens after probably 30 minutes or so. any solution?

Comment: any code you like to share?

Answer (score 1):

The session has probably expired. By default the session duration is 20 minutes. Some solutions :

- Add a javascript on the page that call a "minimal" PHP script every N minutes, just to keep the session active (eg: An AJAX call to a script that only `session_start();exit(0);`).
- Change the settings of your PHP to increase the duration of the session.
- Check the value before to write it, and warn the user that he has no more active session and need to restart his operation.

Comment: thank you, I increased the duration in php.ini file and checked the value before writing it, and up to now, seems no issue had happened at all. thank you again.